# Invalid output of file operation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am not getting proper output for this good:

```
fo=open("test.txt","r+")

print "Name of file:", fo.name

fo.write("Life is short..")

str=fo.read(3)

print "String in file is :",str
fo.close()
```

Comment: "I am not getting proper output for this good"?????

Comment: What are you getting and what do you expect to get? What does `test.txt` look like?

Answer (score 2):

When you open a file in Python, it maintains a single pointer indicating your place in the file. That pointer indicates the next point to be read from and the next point to be written to. It gets updated whenever you read or write. When you write "Life is short...", the file pointer is moved to the end of what you just wrote. That means that when you then go to read from the file, the pointer is already past the part you wrote to. If you want to print out the words you just wrote to the file, you need to move the pointer back to the beginning of the file. This can be accomplished with `fo.seek(0)`.